# Conditions in formula in machine learning

Tags: r, machine-learning, conditional-statements, formula

Is it possible to specify conditions in a formula, for example

```
out1 + out2 ~ in1 + in2 + in3    <with all (out1 + out2 = 1)>
```

a possible example:
Trying to predict a color assembled with `red`, `green` and `blue`. When there are no presumptions about the model, this could possibly be done with a neural network:

```
library("neuralnet")

red <- runif(n=50)
green <- (1 - red) * runif(n=50)
blue <- 1 - red - green

input1 <- green^2
input2 <- sin(red)

trainingdata <- data.frame(red, green, blue, input1, input2)

color.net <- neuralnet(red + green + blue ~ input1 + input2, trainingdata)

test.red <- runif(10)
test.green <- (1 - test.red) * runif(n=10)
test.input1 <- test.green^2
test.input2 <- sin(test.red)

testdata <- data.frame(test.input1, test.input2)

testoutcolor <- as.data.frame(compute(color.net, testdata)[2])
colnames(testoutcolor) <- c("red", "green", "blue")
testoutcolor$sum <- testoutcolor$red + testoutcolor$green + testoutcolor$blue

testoutcolor
```

Even if the `trainingdata` has `red + green + blue = 1` the neural net would most probably not "learn" this condition by itself and only output values approximating this condition.

Is it possible to force the neural net to meet this condition?

**[EDIT]**

As @Spacedman stated, in this example `blue` does not add information to the model - it could be computed just with `1 - red - green`. Still I would need a way to "tell" the model that there is a condition:

```
red + green <= 1
```

Comment: If your three variables add up to 1 then there's no extra information in the third variable and you can leave it off. Can you give a working example, because in `lm` you need to `cbind` the multiple response on the lhs to stop them being simple added.

Comment: Hmm I have to think about that. On the one hand, there's maybe really no extra information in the third variable. On the other hand how should the algorithm know that `out1 + out3` plus a third variable not specified in the model add up to one? I edit my posting to provide an example

Comment: Okay, this looks like a specific neural net/machine learning thing rather than formula in general (including linear models and GLMs). Suggest you modify the title a bit and add a 'neural net' or 'machine learning' tag?

Comment: I think you'll get farther if you present the actual problem you want to solve, rather than asking how to do it with a formula.  There are probably better ways to do it (or better ways to construct a formula)

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a feature to the dataset that returns 1 if the condition is true and 0 (or -1 depending on your activation function) if false, or vice versa. If you ever want to force a ML algorithm to consider something, simply add it as a feature. It will get ignored if it is not predictive by most algorithms.